# Schengen visa expired

Tags: schengen

I'm Colombian. I came to Poland in August 2017 on a visa exemption for the Schengen zone, but I started to work and my employers sent the request for a working permit in November (two days before the expiration of my Schengen period). I received my working permit in December and now I'm waiting for my residency permit, which I've been told can take between 7 months to 1 year to arrive.

My contract finishes in June and my residency was requested up to July 12, 2018. I have several questions regarding my situation.

1. If, by the time my contract finishes, I haven't received my residence, will I have problems at the moment of taking an airplane back home?
2. n case my residence arrives before July 12th, can I stay after that time with the same visa exemption (I’ve read this Schengen exemption reactivates after 6 months immediately after the end of the 90 days allowed for Schengen zone)?
3. If my residency doesn't arrive before July, is there a way to reactivate my Schengen exemption without going back to my own country?

Timeline:

1. August 2017 - Arrival to Poland (no visa).
2. Stayed for 88 days.
3. November 2017 - Request for a working permit.
4. December - I received my working permit.
5. June 2018 - End of contract.
6. July 2018 - End of time residency.

Thanks!

Comment: Not really a travel question. Questions about long term visas, work permits and residency belong on [expatriates.se]

Comment: @HappyM, I'd like to know about what happened next.